# How to check if the previous month has passed in mysql and php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a button 'Save' and a textbox populated with a value of the current date in php.

After the user press the button save, my php script must check if a previous month has passed. For example:

textbox value = '2015-02-01' (let's say its the current date now),

then the user click the 'Save' button.

My php script must say that the date of '2015-01-01' has passed and your in the month of '2015-02-01'. 
I really it for my if condition as:

```
//if a month has passed, 
    # echo "Your in the new month";
//else
    # echo "Your still in this month";
```

I think this has to do with this query:

```
"SELECT SUBDATE('$currentDate', INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AS prevMonth";
```

But how can I complete that and apply it in the condition in my php ? Really need a help here. Thanks

Comment: Why not use [PHP Date and Time Functions?](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php)

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in PHP rather than MySQL:

```
<?php
// Compare mysql result in Y-m format to input in same format
if (date('Y-m', strtotime($mysqlResult)) < date('Y-m', strtotime($textboxValue)))
    echo "You're in the new month (" . date('m') . ")";
else
    echo "You're still in this month."
```

Comment: where this $mysqlResult come from ?

Comment: What exactly constitutes a new month? is it just that the date is the first of the month? What if the date was `2015-02-13'? Would it still return "the month 2015-01-01 has passed" ?

Comment: Yes. Disregard the number of day, just the month is the concern here.

Comment: @Larcy Perhaps I didn't fully understand where the "previous month" in your question is coming from, but `$mysqlResult` represents the previous month you're trying to compare. In your example above, that would be 2015-01-01. `$textboxValue` represents the current date, right?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what your exact requirements are for outputting `you're in a new month`, this is what I got

```
$time = strtotime('2015-02-01');
//Change the string literal to your $_POST variable
if((int)date('j',$time)==1){
    echo "The month of ". date('Y-m-01',$time-1)." has passed";
}else{
    echo "Current month, nevermind";
}
```

Let me know what your requirements are and I can hopefully help you work this out. There really isn't a need for MySQL in this case.

Comment: Let's say the current month now is '2015-02-15', so the month of '2015-01-15 (any day withhin this date)' has passed. If date now is '2015-03-15', then the month of '2015-02-15' has passed again. I want to do this because I need to use this condition during saving the data into my database. There is a separate action in both the current month and previous month during saving. Please help me with this. Thanks

Comment: What exactly is this script going to process and how? With what I am understanding you're just going to continuously have a check of the current date vs 1 month back, and if you try to check if the current time or date is between those two times, it is always going to be true (unless you're trying to set this up to accept a parameter?) Please edit your original question to make it more clear.